# Issue installing Ubuntu via USB - no the normal install instruction forums have not helped

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I'm a new to Linux operating systems and am having some problems installing Ubuntu 14.04.2

I am trying to install it on a HP laptop running Windows 8.1, I have created a separate partition of my hard drive so I can run a dual boot setup.

My laptop has no CD drive so I am trying to load it onto a USB and be able to boot from that and install Ubuntu on my blank partition. Now I recently did this with a Linux Mint partition a couple weeks ago and it worked fine, but I have heard Ubuntu is a better OS so this is the reason for me switching to Ubuntu.

I wiped the Linux mint from the drive and used Universal USB installer (same as I did with Linux mint) to load Ubuntu onto my USB drive and attempted to to install on my blank partition.

But instead of being able to load from the USB, it boots up into GNU GRUB. I have done some research and all the instances I can find of this happening are when Ubuntu is already installed on the PC, nothing stating about it appearing when actually trying to install it.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated as I was really looking forward to learning this OS.

In reference to the questions asked -

Yes I set my computer to boot from the USB, and yes as stated above I used the program Universal USB installer which takes the .iso file and 'installs it' into the USB device.

I will tell you exactly what happens. I select the USB device as the boot device, computer restarts and when it restarts it brings this up:

GNU GRUB  version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possibile comand completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>

And from there on I have no idea what I am supposed to do. It obviously wants me to do something in this cli but I have no clue as to what to put. I most definitely do not have GRUB installed on my windows partition, so it has to be drawing it from my USB.

I have previously tried the advice in the link they posted above and the suggestions that were listed did not work for me, hence why I decided to post it here.

I do not know why this is so difficult to install Ubuntu (spend 5 hours now trying to figure out what to do) and Linux mint I was able to install within minutes. I would think both being Linux operating systems (and being similar in coding from what my OS teacher at my college has told me) that both should be able to be installed without a hitch.

If someone can just explain to me why GNU GRUB is appearing the way it is, and at least point me in the right direction as to what 'possible issue' there is I would be very thankful. As the only record of something like this happening is a grub rescue, which is not this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I'm impressed by the quality of this 1st time post, so +1. Remember, you need to user **2** enter presses to show a new line here! If you forget it can make the text look unapealing to read - like a "wall of text".

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, is that your computer is not starting from the USB device.
Did you set in your BIOS to boot from USB? Did you burn the image on the USB device the right was or did you just copy the iso like a file to the USB device?
What do you mean by: It boot into Grub? Grub is the bootloader. Which Grub? On your harddisc or from USB?

Comment: I have answered your questions above in an edit of my original post since there is a character restriction in comments.